# Dask Dataframe one hot encoding

Tags: python, dask, one-hot-encoding

how to transform ddf labels to one hot encode in the Dask data frame?
labels are int from 1 to 17

here my code :

```
df = dask.dataframe.read_csv('nonTorDataset2.csv', dtype=dicType)

train, test = dask_ml.model_selection.train_test_split(df,test_size=0.2,shuffle=True,blockwise=True)
y_test = train['class_id']
y_test=y_test.astype('category')
y_test=y_test.categorize()
encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
encoder = encoder.fit(y_test)
print(encoder.fit(y_test).compute())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DummyEncoder`.

```
from dask_ml.preprocessing import DummyEncoder

# First categorize your columns.  
ddf = ddf.categorize(["class_id"]) 

# Then generate an encoder. 
encoder = DummyEncoder() 

# Fit the encoder 
ddf_enc = encoder.fit_transform(ddf)  

# Take a look at the data  
ddf_enc.head()
```